# Put user offline when close window or tab

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function stopNavigate() {
    $(window).off('beforeunload');
}

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

$(window).on('unload', function() {
    $.ajax( domain + '/poneOffline' );
);
```

It works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox, it’s not when the user closes the browser. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: it happens because window is closed before request is sent, this will never actually work, it is wrong approach, think what happens when user has several window opened?

Comment: maybe be overkill for what you are doing, i am using SignalR with C# and due to its polling i am able to detect when a user and all their instances are disconnected. though i am doing a full chat app, it may not be worth it just for detecting disconnects.

Comment: Is there any way to do what I am saying?

Comment: Why you want to logout user? Session_timeout on backend side is not enough? And question asked by @Lashane is very good.

Comment: I would do it that way! But in c# you dnt have a session timeout, could just set some kind of update logic in the context dispose logic? That could just log out the user. THe other way would be to set timeout in the cookies...

Comment: I need to know if the user is online or not

Comment: @MartinPiazzon I am personally not sure if above code *should* work (at first glance, from the docs, I could imagine it) but I agree with the other commenters that this is usually not the way to go. Even if you manage the events to work there might be many reasons for your concept to fail, e.g. A browser crash or - as suggested above - multiple open tabs. The common way to achieve what you want is to send a regular ping with JavaScript, which will stop as soon as the user goes offline.